# How to display "tagsinput" vertical?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using Jquery "tagsinput" to let the user creates tags in a input field.

I'd like to display the tags vertical instead of inline.
Also when you type in something like: "1300x1300" it seems like the input doesn't cover 100% in width.

How can i fix this?

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oppningarTd">
      <input type="text" class="oppningar" data-role="tagsinput" multiple="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  white-space: pre; //Just trying something
}

td.oppningarTd {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px !important;
}

input.oppningar {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/Lh4jy9d4/151/

Comment: Make the span elements `display:block`, or float and clear them. (After that, you might want to remove white-space again, and play around with the margins/paddings.)

Comment: @CBroe What span elements?

Comment: The ones this script uses to display the actual tags. Use your browser’s DOM inspector, and look at the elements used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe's comment, i was successful to change the plugin's CSS.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: text;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #777;
  opacity: 1;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
  content: "x";
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```